# Typescript WebDriver/Selenium and PDF Files

Tags: typescript, selenium, webdriver

I had a question about WebDriver/Selenium and PDF Files. I'm running some automated testing using Typescript and Cucumber and everything is working great...except when I got to export a PDF file. I just want to make sure that the PDF file is opened and that we aren't getting a 404.

I can verify that when you click the link (which opens in another tab) that a new window.handle (when calling browser.getWindowHandles) shows up. I can even switch to it by calling browser.switchToWindow(handle)

But when happens after that is any further statement times out with no response. For instance I've tried:
browser.getUrl()
browser.getTitle()

etc...

It never returns. I wanted to get the url and/or the title at least to make sure I didn't get a 404 or something like that. What I had to resort to doing is checking if there is an h1 tag and see if that matches "System Error" (which is the default header in a 404 page). For some reason, trying to grab an element by a selector gracefully times out but browser.getTitle() doesn't. But that's less than ideal.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Selenium needs a DOM to work with... sometimes the browser can be set to display a PDF file which is just that... a PDF file (has no DOM).  Maybe try taking a screenshot, though not sure that it would work either.

Comment: It should work. I don't think a reason for failing to get PDF. Would you mind to share your code and website url if possible?